# Unspecified Error while updating Qt translations(.ts files) in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015, internationalization, qt5

I am trying to update the exisiting translation files using "lupdate" from Qt VSTools. But, it returns with an error code 1 . I tried to clean the solution and rebuild it but this did not help me in solving the issue. I also tried to create a new translation files but it returns with error code 1.

```
lupdate error: File 'GeneratedFiles/ui_file.h' does not exist.
```

It checks for a file that is deleted. Any Suggestions on how to remove that file from lupdate?

Comment: I have the felling some times we need to go there and clean things manually. What happens if you delete all temporary files, build project again and then lupdate it? And I'll guess that file might still be referenced somewhere.. Ctrl+F

Comment: I have tried to clean all the files and recompile the solution but it shows the same error. I tried to search for the file in the project but it did not help.

Comment: Did you see any reference to `ui_file.h` on the `moc_*` files generated during compilation?

Comment: I have deleted all Generated Files and recompiled it. I haven't found any file related to "ui_file.h"

Answer (score 0):

Look for any reference to `ui_file.h` on the `moc_*` files generated during compilation and delete that. That's the surgical manual approach. I've the felling sometimes we are so fast and smart on the keyboard and Qt Creator loose sight of what we are doing then that issue appears.

Another quick way to fix it is by just deleting the `moc_*` files and perhaps other files generated at compile time too.

Answer (score 0):

I have found ui_file.h in external dependencies. Deleting the file solved the issue.